# Change one element in a nested list

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code to make a game board and change one of the elements

```
def firstBoard():
    rows = int(input("Please enter the number of rows: "))
    col = int(input("Please enter the number of columns: "))
    myList = [[0]*col]*rows
    return myList
def getInput(myList):
    rows = int(input("Enter the row or 'q': "))
    col = int(input("enter the column: "))
    myList[rows-1][col-1] = "X"
    return myList

def printBoard(myList):
    for n in myList:
        for s in n:
            print(s, end= " ")
        print()
def main():
    myList = firstBoard()
    myList = getInput(myList)
    print(printBoard(myList))
main()
```

and I want the output for the game board:

```
Please enter the number of rows: 5
Please enter the number of columns: 5
Enter the row or 'q': 1
Enter the column: 1

X 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

but instead I'm getting:

```
X 0 0 0 0 
X 0 0 0 0 
X 0 0 0 0
X 0 0 0 0 
X 0 0 0 0
None
```

Any idea how to fix this and get rid of the "None at the bottom".

Comment: In the fourth line do instead: `myList = [[0]*col for i in range(rows)]` There's an SO answer about this somewhere.

Comment: That worked! Any idea how to get rid of the "None" though? I know that I have to use a return statement instead of print but idk how to return it to make it look like i need it too.

Comment: Since you've already got code to print the board in `printBoard(...)` remove the final call to `print()`, e.g.: the final line in `main()` should be just: `printBoard(myList)`

Comment: Could someone put one of these comments into an answer to close down this question, or could @AlexRochford remove the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comments as an answer...

In the fourth line do instead:

```
myList = [[0]*col for i in range(rows)]
```

The behaviour you were seeing was due to the fact that you were creating the same list on each row.

And since you've already got code to print the board in `printBoard(...)` remove the final call to `print()`, e.g.: the final line in `main()` should be just:

```
printBoard(myList)
```